# Install plasTeX on Windows 7

Tags: windows, html, xml

[PlasTeX](http://plastex.sourceforge.net/) is a free, open-source tool to process (La)TeX files and convert them to xHTML by default, but also docbook, text, and others.  It is fully customizable.

How do I install plasTeX on Windows 7?  Give detailed steps and instructions to get a working plastex command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows 7 (using plasTex 0.9.2):

1. Install the pre-requisites:

   a. A good LaTeX installation (I used TeXLive.  plasTeX would not work for me until it was there.)

   b. Python (I used ActiveState python 2.7)
2. Download plasTeX from http://sourceforge.net/projects/plastex/files/
3. Use a tool like 7zip to expand the file plastex-0.9.2.tgz (865.9 kB).
4. Install the plastex package into python

   a.  Open a command prompt and cd into the plastex directory containing setup.py:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\David\Downloads\plastex\plastex
   ```

   (in this example for directories that came from expanding  C:\Users\David\Downloads\plastex-0.9.2.tgz)

   b.  In your command prompt, type

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```
5. then create a text file C:\Python27\Scripts\plastex.bat containing

   ```
   c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\Scripts\plastex %*
   ```

   (Note that you have to have the * or it will only get your first argument to plastex.)

Now when you open a new command prompt (that can see the plastex command because the installation commands put c:\python27\Scripts into your PATH environment variable.)

You can type

```
  plastex MyFile.tex
```

and plastex should create a MyFile folder in that directory containing an index.html file.

plasTeX documenation is in the package, and also in Tim Arnold's article

http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-3/arnold/arnold.pdf

(Tim's article in html form: http://plastex.sourceforge.net/getting-started/)

Comment: Is this Windows only? If so, it would be helpful to make that clear.

Comment: plasTeX works on any platform with python.  These instructions help with some hurdles for Windows 7 (and other Windows OS's).  Edited answer, thanks.